# Permissions to delete media file on Android 11+

Tags: flutter, android-permissions

I am building and mp3 player with `permission_handler` plugin to mange permissions. Reading audios with granted `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` permission is no problem, but not deleting them.

When trying to delete a file like this:

```
void deleteFile(String filePath) {
  File file = File( filePath );
  try {
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      print('file exists $file');
      file.deleteSync();
    }
  } catch (e) { print(e); }
}
```

It says:

> **file exists** File: '/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/05 - Sharpshooter (1).mp3'
> **PathNotFoundException**: Cannot delete file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/05 - Sharpshooter (1).mp3' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

As far as I understand `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` doesn't work in Android 11 and above (I am using 13) because of *scoped storage*, so:

```
// adding this to AndroidManifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

// using this in app code
Permission.storage.request()
```

won't do a thing... and adding `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is obviously not the way to go.

In other modern music player / gallery apps, system asks for permission to delete the exact selected files. Probably utilizing something called `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest()` from native Android (I am not an Android dev).

What is Flultter solution to delete media files on Android 11+ ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is [media_store_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/media_store_plus) package, which uses method channels for removing/managing media from other folder than the data folder of the app in newer Android versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This plugin looks promising but underdeveloped, I decided to try and implement delete feature with native side.